# Determining if a given complex function is the anti-derivative of another function.

Tags: complex-analysis

For this problem, I'm asked to verify that $F(z) = \frac{i}{2}\text{Log}(z + i) -\frac{i}{2}\text{Log}(z - i)$ is an anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ for Re$(z)>0$. I'd like to use familiar rules of Logarithms to transform this to $\frac{i}{2}\text{Log}(\frac{z+i}{z-i})$, but I don't know if this is 1) valid or 2) the correct approach even if it is valid. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it not simpler to differentiate them separately than combining them anyway?

Comment: You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

(1) It is valid - see below.  (2) It is a correct approach, but, as pointed out by @Sobi in a comment, not the simplest approach.

We show that if ${\rm Re}(z)>0$ then
$$\def\Log{\mathop{\rm Log}\nolimits}
  \Log(z+i)-\Log(z-i)=\Log\Bigl(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\Bigr)\ ,$$
where the principal logarithm is defined by
$$\Log(w)=\Log(re^{i\theta})=\ln r+i\theta\qquad\hbox{with}\ -\pi<\theta\le\pi\ .$$
If ${\rm Re}(z)>0$ then $z$ is in the first or fourth quadrant, and it is easy to see from a diagram that $z+i$ and and $z-i$ are also in the first or fourth quadrant.  So we can write polar forms
$$z+i=re^{i\theta}\ ,\quad z-i=se^{i\phi}\qquad
  \hbox{with}\ -\frac\pi2<\theta,\phi\le\frac\pi2\ .$$
Hence
$$\Log(z+i)-\Log(z-i)=\bigl(\ln r+i\theta\bigr)-\bigl(\ln s+i\phi\bigr)
  =\ln\frac rs+i(\theta-\phi)\ .$$
Also
$$\frac{z+i}{z-i}=\frac rs\,e^{i(\theta-\phi)}$$
and we have
$$-\pi<\theta-\phi<\pi\ ,$$
so
$$\Log\Bigl(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\Bigr)=\ln\frac rs+i(\theta-\phi)$$
as required.

Note that this may not work if $z$ is in the second or third quadrant.  I leave you to do the calculations carefully when $z=-\frac1{\sqrt3}$ and confirm that ${\rm LHS}\ne{\rm RHS}$.